# WndProc not getting called in C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform, I'm trying to do something on `WM_CHAR`. But Code is not hitting breakpoints.

```
    public const int WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION = 0x0010E;
    public const int WM_IME_COMPOSITION = 0x0010F;
    public const int WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION = 0x0010D;
    public const int WM_IME_CHAR = 0x00286;
    public const int WM_CHAR = 0x00102;
    public const int WM_IME_NOTIFY = 0x00282;
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
    public const int WM_IME_SETCONTEXT = 0x00281;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {

        switch (m.Msg)
        {

            case WM_IME_CHAR:
                long lParam1 = m.LParam.ToInt64();
                long wParam1 = m.WParam.ToInt64();
                char c1 = (char)m.WParam;
                break;

            case WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION:
                long lParam2 = m.LParam.ToInt64();
                long wParam2 = m.WParam.ToInt64();
                char c2 = (char)m.WParam;

                break;

            case 0x00102:
                long lParam3 = m.LParam.ToInt64();
                long wParam3 = m.WParam.ToInt64();
                char c3 = (char)m.WParam;

                break;

            case WM_IME_COMPOSITION:
                long lParam44 = m.LParam.ToInt64();
                long wParam = m.WParam.ToInt64();
                char c4 = (char)m.WParam;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe there's another control in focus that handles the WM_CHAR before you ?

Comment: A message like WM_CHAR is sent to the control that has the focus.  Nobody can tell what class' WndProc() method you overrode but it is highly predictable that it is not the class of the control.  There are much better ways to do this but you didn't ask for them or bothered to describe what you actually want to achieve.